# how to handle 2 different combobox itemListener in same itemlistener function?

Tags: java, combobox, itemlistener

I Have two ComboBoxes

```
JcomboBox1.addItemListener(this)
jComboBox2.addItemListener(this)
```

How can I handle these in the same itemListener Function?
I am handling it for 1 combobox but need to handle with both combo box

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
       String Product=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
          ResultSet rs=db.GetPriceOfaProduct(Product);
          try{
              rs.next();
              int price=rs.getInt("pPrice");
             jLabel6.setText("Amount Per Item is "+price);
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("Error in Taking Product Price");
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ItemEvent.getSource()` to check which `JComboBox` has changed selection.

**Please be aware on changing selection, the item listener will be notified twice, once on the item deselected, followed by another on the item selected.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] { "11", "12" });
    JComboBox<String> comboBox2 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] { "21", "22" });
    ItemListener listener = (e) -> {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if (e.getSource() == comboBox1) {
                System.out.printf("JComboBox 1 state changed: %s selected\n", e.getItem());
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == comboBox2) {
                System.out.printf("JComboBox 2 state changed: %s selected\n", e.getItem());
            }
        }
    };
    comboBox1.addItemListener(listener);
    comboBox2.addItemListener(listener);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `comboBox1.getSelectedItem()` or `comboBox2.getSelectedItem()`, you can use `JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) ie.getItem();` - you then have a reference to whichever JComboBox triggered the event.

---

Use `getSource()` not `getItem()`

Comment: `getSource()` returns the `JComboBox`, `getItem()` returns the selected value.